# Upgraded Django(1.11) & Django-cms(3.5.0) - pages no longer appearing

Tags: python, django, django-cms

So I've successfully upgraded a django site (django 1.4 - 1.11. Python 2.5 - 3.5. Django-CMS 2.4 - 3.5) I started with a fresh database, made the migrations, migrated and everything went fine. No conflicts, no issues.

*Yes I'm doing it all locally for now. My internet is horrific so I'd rather do it locally, get it working then deploy it.*

Now I come to the site, enter the admin, everything is there except one particular plugin (snippets) and there are no pages. At all. Everything else is fine though and when I go to publish an empty page, I get the following error:

```
Exception Type: IntegrityError at /en/cms_wizard/create/
Exception Value: (1452, 'Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`eo_web_live`.`cms_page`, CONSTRAINT `site_id_refs_id_5f61f09c` FOREIGN KEY (`site_id`) REFERENCES `django_site` (`id`))')
```

Here is the full traceback with settings:

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/en/cms_wizard/create/

Django Version: 1.11.10
Python Version: 3.6.3
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django_comments',
 'djangocms_admin_style',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'djangocms_text_ckeditor',
 'cms',
 'mptt',
 'menus',
 'treebeard',
 'filer',
 'easy_thumbnails',
 'sekizai',
 'reversion',
 'gunicorn',
 'compressor',
 'form_designer',
 'store_locator',
 'cms_redirects',
 'eo_registration',
 'eo_jobs',
 'djangocms_link',
 'djangocms_file',
 'djangocms_picture',
 'djangocms_video',
 'djangocms_googlemap',
 'djangocms_snippet',
 'djangocms_style',
 'djangocms_column',
 'cmsplugin_filer_file',
 'cmsplugin_filer_folder',
 'cmsplugin_filer_link',
 'cmsplugin_filer_image',
 'cmsplugin_filer_teaser',
 'cmsplugin_filer_video',
 'eo_cms',
 'eo_cms.plugins.feature_block',
 'eo_cms.plugins.teaser_block',
 'eo_cms.plugins.profile_block',
 'eo_cms.plugins.accordion_block',
 'eo_cms.plugins.tabbed_block',
 'eo_jobs.plugins.job_listings_block',
 'tagging',
 'eo_zinnia_blog_theme',
 'cmsplugin_zinnia',
 'zinnia',
 'eo_survey',
 'eo_consultants',
 'eo_consultants.plugins.consultants_block',
 'eo_consultants.plugins.consultant_profile_block',
 'rosetta',
 'bootstrapform',
 'helpdesk')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.admindocs.middleware.XViewMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.http.ConditionalGetMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'cms.middleware.language.LanguageCookieMiddleware',
 'cms.middleware.page.CurrentPageMiddleware',
 'cms.middleware.user.CurrentUserMiddleware',
 'cms.middleware.toolbar.ToolbarMiddleware',
 'cms_redirects.middleware.RedirectFallbackMiddleware')



Traceback:

File "/home/tom/Desktop/EO/development/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  64.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "/home/tom/Desktop/EO/development/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py" in execute
  101.             return self.cursor.execute(query, args)

File "/home/tom/Desktop/EO/development/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mysqlclient-1.3.12-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg/MySQLdb/cursors.py" in execute
  250.             self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)

File "/home/tom/Desktop/EO/development/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mysqlclient-1.3.12-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg/MySQLdb/connections.py" in defaulterrorhandler
  50.         raise errorvalue

File "/home/tom/Desktop/EO/development/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mysqlclient-1.3.12-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg/MySQLdb/cursors.py" in execute
  247.             res = self._query(query)

File "/home/tom/Desktop/EO/development/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mysqlclient-1.3.12-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg/MySQLdb/cursors.py" in _query
  411.         rowcount = self._do_query(q)

File "/home/tom/Desktop/EO/development/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mysqlclient-1.3.12-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg/MySQLdb/cursors.py" in _do_query
  374.         db.query(q)

File "/home/tom/Desktop/EO/development/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mysqlclient-1.3.12-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg/MySQLdb/connections.py" in query
  277.             _mysql.connection.query(self, query)

The above exception ((1452, 'Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`eo_web_live`.`cms_page`, CONSTRAINT `site_id_refs_id_5f61f09c` FOREIGN KEY (`site_id`) REFERENCES `django_site` (`id`))')) was the direct cause of the following exception:

File "/home/tom/Desktop/EO/development/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  41.             response = get_response(request)

File "/home/tom/Desktop/EO/development/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _legacy_get_response
  249.             response = self._get_response(request)

File "/home/tom/Desktop/EO/development/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/home/tom/Desktop/EO/development/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/home/tom/Desktop/EO/development/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  68.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/tom/Desktop/EO/development/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cms/wizards/views.py" in dispatch
  45.         return super(WizardCreateView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

File "/home/tom/Desktop/EO/development/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/formtools/wizard/views.py" in dispatch
  248.         response = super(WizardView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/tom/Desktop/EO/development/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in dispatch
  88.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/tom/Desktop/EO/development/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/formtools/wizard/views.py" in post
  309.                 return self.render_done(form, **kwargs)

File "/home/tom/Desktop/EO/development/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/formtools/wizard/views.py" in render_done
  365.         done_response = self.done(final_forms.values(), form_dict=final_forms, **kwargs)

File "/home/tom/Desktop/EO/development/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cms/wizards/views.py" in done
  145.         instance = form_two.save()

File "/usr/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py" in inner
  52.                 return func(*args, **kwds)

File "/home/tom/Desktop/EO/development/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cms/forms/wizards.py" in save
  160.         new_page = super(CreateCMSPageForm, self).save(**kwargs)

File "/home/tom/Desktop/EO/development/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cms/admin/forms.py" in save
  272.             new_page.save()

File "/home/tom/Desktop/EO/development/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cms/models/pagemodel.py" in save
  762.         super(Page, self).save(**kwargs)

File "/home/tom/Desktop/EO/development/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save
  808.                        force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)

File "/home/tom/Desktop/EO/development/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cms/models/pagemodel.py" in save_base
  777.         return super(Page, self).save_base(*args, **kwargs)

File "/home/tom/Desktop/EO/development/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save_base
  838.             updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)

File "/home/tom/Desktop/EO/development/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in _save_table
  924.             result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)

File "/home/tom/Desktop/EO/development/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in _do_insert
  963.                                using=using, raw=raw)

File "/home/tom/Desktop/EO/development/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in manager_method
  85.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)

File "/home/tom/Desktop/EO/development/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _insert
  1076.         return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)

File "/home/tom/Desktop/EO/development/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  1112.                 cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "/home/tom/Desktop/EO/development/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  79.             return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)

File "/home/tom/Desktop/EO/development/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  64.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "/home/tom/Desktop/EO/development/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py" in __exit__
  94.                 six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)

File "/home/tom/Desktop/EO/development/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/six.py" in reraise
  685.             raise value.with_traceback(tb)

File "/home/tom/Desktop/EO/development/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  64.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "/home/tom/Desktop/EO/development/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py" in execute
  101.             return self.cursor.execute(query, args)

File "/home/tom/Desktop/EO/development/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mysqlclient-1.3.12-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg/MySQLdb/cursors.py" in execute
  250.             self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)

File "/home/tom/Desktop/EO/development/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mysqlclient-1.3.12-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg/MySQLdb/connections.py" in defaulterrorhandler
  50.         raise errorvalue

File "/home/tom/Desktop/EO/development/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mysqlclient-1.3.12-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg/MySQLdb/cursors.py" in execute
  247.             res = self._query(query)

File "/home/tom/Desktop/EO/development/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mysqlclient-1.3.12-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg/MySQLdb/cursors.py" in _query
  411.         rowcount = self._do_query(q)

File "/home/tom/Desktop/EO/development/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mysqlclient-1.3.12-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg/MySQLdb/cursors.py" in _do_query
  374.         db.query(q)

File "/home/tom/Desktop/EO/development/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mysqlclient-1.3.12-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg/MySQLdb/connections.py" in query
  277.             _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
```

From what I can figure out, it seems to be an error with the fact that the 'site-id' references the 'django-site(id)' but I cannot for the life of me find where a site-id is referencing anything in the database.

**UPDATE**

So after searching around and finding a few commands to check both the DB engine for the tables and confirming they're all the same I came across this interesting section:

```
CONSTRAINT `site_id_refs_id_5f61f09c` FOREIGN KEY (`site_id`) REFERENCES `django_site` (`id`)
Trying to add in child table, in index cms_page_99732b5c tuple:
DATA TUPLE: 2 fields;
 0: len 4; hex 80000000; asc     ;;
 1: len 4; hex 80005970; asc   Yp;;

But in parent table `eo_web_live`.`django_site`, in index PRIMARY,
the closest match we can find is record:
PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 5; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 4; hex 80000001; asc     ;;
 1: len 6; hex 00000000f556; asc      V;;
 2: len 7; hex bc000001480110; asc     H  ;;
 3: len 24; hex 7777772e657865637574697665736f6e6c696e652e6e6574; asc www.companysite.com;;
 4: len 24; hex 7777772e657865637574697665736f6e6c696e652e6e6574; asc www.companysite.com;;
```

Which looks like the physical ID of both the site and the page are saved as a completely new hex value (much much higher length) which I'm guessing is a feature of either new Django or new Django-CMS.

I'm not sure whether this means I'll have to change the old values or if something else entirely is wrong.

Any help or helpful insults would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you run the migrate command after upgrading the app?

Comment: @Walucas Yes, I did. I have a feeling I might have to start again, remove the migrations and start the process again but I'm just not sure if that would even help.

Comment: Hello Tom, did you migrate directly from 2.4 to 3.5?

Comment: Hi Paulo. Yes I did. I was told that it was generally safe (and easier) to just go for it, find and fix any errors that come up and get on with it. It did throw quite a few errors initially but I have the majority of everything working, I can see the rest of the apps, just nothing from the old CMS setup.

Comment: I also changed all of the migrations (Deleted old South migrations and ran makemigrations again to start the new migrations).

Comment: Going from 2.4 directly to 3.5 is not recommended, I suggest instead to go from 2.4 to 3.0 first, then move to 3.4 and from 3.4 move to 3.5.

Comment: Is this simply due to deprecations? I realise there are a lot in 3.0 that breaks with 2.4 but is it the same for 3.4 and 3.5? Thank you by the way.

Comment: Yes but also because of migrations and upgrade steps, there's a section on the docs for migrating a project from 2.4 to 3.0, there's quite a lot of steps and missing one could result in unstable db. I usually recommend (and practice) to migrate to 3.0, and stay there for a week, then 3.4, stay there a week and then 3.5. The reason for that is to isolate issues (if any) to specific releases.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you so much! I guess it's just a matter of taking my time, being careful and reading the release notes properly. I'd just read somewhere that as long as you were aware of the major breaking changes that the simplest way was to just upgrade completely and work through any issues.